# QJackCtl Scripting start alsa_in after launch

Tags: linux, audio, alsa, jack

so I'm trying to get QJackCtl to launch an instance of alsa_in to control an extra audio device after I start the Jack server. I've put this code in the execute after startup section:

```
alsa_in -j ZOOM -d hw:CARD=Series
```

which resulted in hanging QJackCtl until I killed alsa_in in sys monitor.
I then tried replacing that with

```
gnome-terminal -e alsa_in -j ZOOM -d hw:CARD=Series
```

to launch it in the terminal instead hoping this would work,
as it turns out it didn't and I don't really understand how the scripting for QJackCtl works, so any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I got 2 USB devices added and working in Jack by saving the following code as a shell script on my desktop, making it executable and then linking to the script in QjackCtl to execute after startup:

```
#!/bin/dash
/usr/bin/alsa_in -j "Logitech USB Microphone" -d hw:Microphone -q 1 2>&1 1> /dev/null &
/usr/bin/alsa_in -j "Logitech USB Microphone" -d hw:Microphone_1 -q 1 2>&1 1> /dev/null &
echo "USB mics added"
```

Worked great for me so I hope that helps you too.